# PDF not viewing on browser instead its downloding in both firefox and chrome

Tags: php, html, pdf

I Have try to view pdf from below mention 3 ways and it all foecing to download the pdf not viewing it in browser.can anyone suggest me a better solution for viewing pdf in browser.

```
 echo "<embed src=\"Report/invoiceRepoet.pdf\" width=\"100%\" style=\"height:100%\" />";
```

......................................................................................................

```
 echo "<iframe src=\"Report/invoiceRepoet.pdf\" width=\"100%\" style=\"height:100%\"></iframe>";
```

......................................................................................................

```
$filePath="invoiceRepoet.pdf";
$filename="invoiceRepoet.pdf";
header('Content-type:application/pdf');
header('Content-disposition: inline; filename="'.$filename.'"');
header('content-Transfer-Encoding:binary');
header('Accept-Ranges:bytes');
@ readfile($filePath);
```

Comment: Not really something you can control.  Depends on browser configuration and extensions loaded (or not).

Comment: Embedding PDF won't work in android browsers so you can use any PDF Viewer js library to convert it as html and display on the browser.

Comment: Adobe has recently released it's Document Cloud View SDK. A client-side JavaScript viewer for PDF - https://www.adobe.io/apis/documentcloud/dcsdk/viewsdk.html

Comment: Thank you everyone. but i found a solution for this.best way to view pdf from browser is to use [PDF.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js)